# Eclipse's launching configuration TabGroup doesn't show up

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, gdb, launcher

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin based on gdb-plugin. As said [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/cdt-debug-dsf-gdb-extensibility) I extended necessary classes (e.g. GdbLaunchDelegate) and as said, for example, [here](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html), added necessary information to Eclipse's extension points:

```
  <launchDelegate
delegate="neuromatrixplugin.fifoblocks.backbone.FIFOGdbLaunchDelegate"
        delegateDescription="FIFO Blocks GDB Launch Delegate 1"
        id="neuromatrixplugin.fifoblocks.backbone.FIFOGdbLaunchDelegate"
        modes="debug"
        name="FIFO Blocks GDB Launch Delegate"
        sourceLocatorId="org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.sourceLocator"
        sourcePathComputerId="org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.sourcePathComputer"
        type="org.eclipse.cdt.debug.gdbjtag.launchConfigurationType">
  </launchDelegate>
```

The problem is: tab group responsible for launch information doesn't appear with my launch delegate set so no information can be passed to delegate and it fails.

[image: Launch window]

In the debug mode I noticed that TabGroup class *gets* instatiated (i.e. constructor is called, but returns no tabs). Adding specific launching types for my delegate (seen in the menu on the left) changed nothing.

Does anyone know what may cause that behaviour?

**UPD** The problem is most likely in extension point because even when I set original GdbLaunchDelegate itself TabGroup doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Tabs should also be registered in extension points list separately like [there](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt/+/CDT_8_0_2/jtag/org.eclipse.cdt.debug.gdbjtag.ui/plugin.xml). It's strange because it isn't mentioned in tutorials and isn't always necessary.